How to update SwiftData store from actor?
How do I go about saving the new FHIRObservations to SwiftData? My current approach await self.model?.updateObservations(newObservations: fhirResources, deletedObservations: uuidsToDelete) leads to a race condition according to Swift 6 since I'm trying to send fhiresources:
Sending 'self'-isolated 'fhirResources' to main actor-isolated instance method 'updateObservations(newObservations:deletedObservations:)' risks causing data races between main actor-isolated and 'self'-isolated uses

I'm also unclear as to how I'd update my data store with the newly fetched resources. Any help would be appreciated!
I have the following model class:
@Model
public final class FHIRObservation {
    @Attribute(.allowsCloudEncryption) let hkID: UUID
    @Attribute(.allowsCloudEncryption) let fhirID: String
    @Attribute(.allowsCloudEncryption) var name: String
    @Attribute(.allowsCloudEncryption) var status: String
    @Attribute(.allowsCloudEncryption) var code: FHIRCodeableConcept
    @Attribute(.allowsCloudEncryption) var value: FHIRLabValueType
    @Attribute(.allowsCloudEncryption) var range: FHIRLabRange?
    @Attribute(.allowsCloudEncryption) var lastUpdated: Date?
    
    init(hkID: UUID, fhirID: String, name: String, status: String, code: FHIRCodeableConcept, value: FHIRLabValueType, range: FHIRLabRange? = nil, lastUpdated: Date? = nil) {
        self.hkID = hkID
        self.fhirID = fhirID
        self.name = name
        self.status = status
        self.code = code
        self.value = value
        self.range = range
        self.lastUpdated = lastUpdated
    }
}

the following class UserData:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import os

@MainActor
public class UserData: ObservableObject {

    let userDataLogger = Logger(
        subsystem:
            "com.cyrilzakka.Cardya.UserData",
        category: "Model")
    
    public static let shared = UserData()
    public lazy var healthKitManager = HKManager(withModel: self)
        
    func updateObservations(newObservations: [FHIRObservation], deletedObservations: [UUID]) async {
        
        // TODO: Delete and add objects using Swift Data
    }
}

and the following actor HKManager:
public actor HKManager {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    private lazy var isAuthorized = false
    private weak var model: UserData?
    ...
    @discardableResult
    public func loadLabResults() async -> Bool {
        guard isAvailable else {
            hkLogger.debug("HealthKit is not available on this device.")
            return false
        }
        hkLogger.debug("Loading lab results from HealthKit")
        
        do {
            let (samples, deletedSamples, newAnchor) = try await queryLabResults()
            self.anchor = newAnchor
            
            guard let samples = samples else {
                hkLogger.debug("Lab results returned by HealthKit are empty.")
                return false
            }
            
            // Cast from HKSample to HKClinicalRecord, extract HKFHIRResource and convert to ObservationProtocol
            let fhirResources = try samples.compactMap { sample -> FHIRObservation? in
                guard let clinicalRecord = sample as? HKClinicalRecord,
                          let fhirResource = clinicalRecord.fhirResource else {
                        return nil
                }
                let item = try self.displayObservationConvertible(for: fhirResource)
                return FHIRObservation(hkID: sample.uuid, fhirID: fhirResource.identifier, name: clinicalRecord.displayName, status: item.labStatus, code: item.labCoding, value: item.labValue, range: item.labRange, lastUpdated: item.lastUpdated)
            }
            
            // Get IDs of observations to be deleted
            var uuidsToDelete: [UUID] = []
            if let deletedSamples = deletedSamples, !deletedSamples.isEmpty {
                uuidsToDelete = deletedSamples.lazy.map { deletedObject -> UUID in
                    if let uuidString = deletedObject.metadata?[HKMetadataKeySyncIdentifier] as? String,
                       let uuid = UUID(uuidString: uuidString) {
                        return uuid
                    }
                    return deletedObject.uuid
                }
            }
            
            // THIS CAUSES AN ERROR:
            
//            await self.model?.updateObservations(newObservations: fhirResources, deletedObservations: uuidsToDelete)
            
            return true
        } catch {
            hkLogger.error("An error occurred while querying for samples: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return false
        }
    }

Update 1:
I've created a FHIRObservationWrapper with the same properties as FHIRObservation that conforms to Sendable which seems to have fixed the problem. Is that considered okay?

If the wrapper is sendable then that is ok, another option is to pass an array of persistentModelID instead of the model objects since the identifier (PersistentIdentifer) is sendable and then load each model in the called function if needed

@JoakimDanielson I'm unfamiliar with some of those terms. Would you mind sharing some resources or an example? And thank you!

When you use the @Model on a class it will make the class conform to the PersistentModel protocol. So reading the documentation for that is a good start
